# Faster to use JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile app made in HTML, CSS and jQuery, which will be used with phonegap.

Is the app likely to run faster if I go back through and change things to pure JavaScript and get rid of the jQuery framework?

EDIT:

my code is fairly simple, however (i guess?) quite long at about 1500 lines of code.

Most of it is things like:

```
function checkPagesChange(desiredPage){

if(desiredPage === 'page-search-results'){

    $('#search-results-info').show()
    $('.current-job').removeClass('current-job').remove()
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:scrollPosition},40)   

}else{

    $('#search-results-info').hide()
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:'0'},40)      

}

if(desiredPage === 'page-search'){

    $('#back-nav').hide();
    $('#search-icon').hide();
    closeAskToSave()

}else{

    $('#back-nav').show();
    $('#search-icon').show()

}

if(desiredPage === 'page-view-job'){

    $('#job-nav').show();

}else{

    $('#job-nav').hide();

}

if(desiredPage === 'page-view-saved-job'){

    $('#saved-job-nav').show();

}else{

    $('#saved-job-nav').hide();

}

}
```

which would be pretty simple to change to pure JavaScript. But then I do use things like fadeIn() and animate() which are a lot simpler with jQuery.

Maybe a hybrid of jQuery and Javascript would be best? keep jQuery methods for certain things (i.e fadeIn()) but use javascript elsewhere?

or, is jQuery really not much slower anyway?

Comment: Yes, even if what you write is as bad as the worst jQ code, it'll still outperform that badly written jQ code. However, bad code doesn't become _good_ code, just by ditching jQ... the problem is often the person writing it

Comment: if the code is small go with javascript, else stick to jquery and go with dystroy's suggestion.

Comment: jQuery is very well written javascript. Don't plan to switch to javascript unless you can match jQuery's code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will go faster. But not much faster and you'll have made your code more complex.

If your page using jQuery is slow, don't remove jQuery, find the weakness by profiling and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Well written native JavaScript will pretty much always be faster. How much depends on what you're doing and what jQuery is doing 'behind the scenes' for compatibility. However, the question is, are you better at writing vanilla JS than the jQuery guys are (while also bloating it slightly to back-fill compatibility). Its not always as simple as plain old JS > jQuery. The quality of your code will very much play a part.